# How do I get the URL before routing?

Tags: go

I want to get the url or the neme of the route before routing it, ex:

```
router.HandleFunc("/person", person.HandlePerson)
router.HandleFunc("/animal", animal.HandleAnimal)
```

I want to know the route before routing like this:

```
nameOfRoute:=    //I want this variable to store the name of the route (person or animal) before routing 
fmt.Println(nameOfRoute) //This line will print the name of the route ("/animal", "/person")
router.HandleFunc("/person", person.HandlePerson)
router.HandleFunc("/animal", animal.HandleAnimal)
```

How can I do this in Golang

Comment: did you try `nameOfRoute := "/animal"` and then `router.HandleFunc(nameOfroute, animal.HandleAnimal)`?

Comment: yes, I want this
but I want nameOfRoute to store it from the url
I won't initialize it

Comment: I don't know the value of the route, So i want to know it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot — in the sense that you showed. That's because the statements

```golang
router.HandleFunc("/person", person.HandlePerson)
```

are not actions which carry out actual routing but rather directives to the router about how it should do routing.
The routing itself is handler via a single "entry" function of your router.

What you can do, however, is to employ "cascading" of several routers:

1. Create a router which handles `/`, and then create another router which handles all your indiviual routes — as it's currently done.
2. Make the sole handler function of the first — root — router print the URL and then merely call the inner's router entry function.
   I have no idea which router package are you using (there are gazillions of them, including the stock one) so I cannot tell you what that function is; in a stock router it's `ServeHTTP`.
   Please consider figuring this out as a homework ;-)

With a stock `net/http`'s `ServeMux`, you do not even need a root router because a single function would do — something like this:

```golang
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("/person", whatever)
...

server := http.Server{
  Handler: func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(r.URL)
    mux.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  },
}

server.ListenAndServe()
```